# Strange error with PHP str_replace &$count argument

Tags: php, codeigniter, pass-by-reference, str-replace

In Codeigniter controller I have this statement:

$txt = str_replace($t, $bracketted_var, $txt, &$count);

$count variable is passed by reference and I'm using it's changed value later in program.

Discovered that on new installation with PHP/5.3.3-7 calling that controller gives me in Firefox this response:

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading

Without any log entry in Apache access log. In Error log I noticed two entries:
[Mon Aug 26 12:12:28 2013] [notice] child pid 32048 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Aug 26 12:12:28 2013] [notice] child pid 32082 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

I tried a couple of other browsers and Androind and iPhone too without getting a web page content.

The statement wasn't in the function that was called. It looks like some kind of syntax error arise during parsing php file.

Searching for a solution I discovered that this str_replace statement doesn't give that error:

$txt = str_replace($t, $bracketted_var, $txt, $count);

I did temporarily make change so that other parts of controller are working.
But I need to use a changed $count variable with a number of changes. Any suggestions?

Searching I didn't find anything usefull about such an error.

Comment: $txt = str_replace($t, $bracketted_var, $txt, $count); should be ok, $count is being passed in by reference

Comment: Have this as a thumb rule; if your php or server is acting up, it's less likely that it's a browser problem. Browser checking is more relevant concerning `html`, `javascript` and `css`. No need to test this problem out on different browsers, that is.

Comment: Robin: I had a same error message (The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading) in Firefox earlier and it was a cookie problem. So I started with browser(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call time pass by refernence is deprecated (in PHP > v5.3, it's utterly removed in v5.4 at which point it'll raise a fatal error). You can leave it as you have it now, `$count` should be updatet as it is denoted as a reference by the `str_replace` itself.

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php
and http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Thanks. I should also check all other usage of pass by reference. I notice a lot of them, but probably accepting & setting is working?

Comment: Strange for me is that the parsing actually arised fatal error and a process was killed!?

Comment: It shoudb't before 5.4. Probably a subsequent error or an uncaught excpetion occurred as a result of the error itself.

Comment: That function wasn't executed just parsed!?

Comment: well yeah, it's a compile-time error (see also http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.allow-call-time-pass-reference); however it should still throw E_DEPRECATED, not fatal. However, depending on your .ini settings that can result in a conn. reset.